# unittest discover with pattern for multiple files

Tags: python, python-unittest, ironpython

what will be the way to pass multiple files to the pattern in unittest discover?
it looks like it is using Shell patterns and from source code I see that `fnmatch` is used.

goal is to run multiple IronPython jobs concurrently that started from CPython (we need cross-platform func)

```
C:\IronPython\net45\ipy.exe -m unittest discover -s C:\git\TEST\Common -p "test1.py test2.py" -t C:\git\TEST\Common
```

is it possible to pass multiple files as a pattern for unittests?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple `-p` arguments one after the other, e.g. `-p arg1 -p arg2`.

In your case,
`C:\IronPython\net45\ipy.exe -m unittest discover -s C:\git\TEST\Common -p "test1.py" -p "test2.py" -t C:\git\TEST\Common` should do the trick!